# ZipException during project build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-build

I'm updating Android studio and plugin for version 3.4 (gradle for version 5.1.1) When I try build project, I get an error

> java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty

I download gradle-5.1.1-all.zip and tried replace existing but it was unsuccessfully.

Any ideas what cause this error?

log

```
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution     failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDevDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)

    *****

    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    *****

Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:442)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:273)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ArchiveClassFileProvider.<init>(ArchiveClassFileProvider.java:63)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ArchiveClassFileProvider.<init>(ArchiveClassFileProvider.java:50)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.r8.CachingArchiveClassFileProvider.<init>(CachingArchiveClassFileProvider.java:32)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.r8.ClassFileProviderFactory.createProvider(ClassFileProviderFactory.java:123)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.r8.ClassFileProviderFactory.<init>(ClassFileProviderFactory.java:93)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:363)
```

Build tools 28.0.3

Comment: This looks like an interrupted download error to me.
Can you try deleting the `~.gradle` folder from your system?

Comment: I tryed it also. Same situation

Answer (score 8):

One of the causes of this problem is the [decommissioning of HTTP services by Gradle](https://blog.gradle.org/decommissioning-http). This means that if your `[PROJECT_PATH]/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file has an entry like:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{version}.zip
```

... then this entry will try to retrieve a `ZIP` file from a service no longer accessible through `http` and it will silently return an empty `ZIP` file; which consequentially will be the source of an error from any process trying to unzip that empty `ZIP` file.

To fix this, just change your `[PROJECT_PATH]/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file to have its `distributionUrl` entry to use `https`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-{version}.zip
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to recreate a gradle wrapper. It seems to me, you use old version of it. 
I fixed the same issues in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem with your JDK not being installed correctly (perhaps on update) or linked correctly to your build in your updated Android Studio IDE.

Start with making sure the JDK setup is correct in Android Studio, then work your way back toward the JDK itself. Try to reinstall the JDK on your machine.

Comment: JDK installed correctly.another project builds completely